# How to add brackets to the command \eqref{#1} with the package refstyle?

Tags: eqref, refstyle

Just like the following MWE, I'd like to use the `refstyle` package to create a series of commands like `\eqref{#1}` and `\Eqref{#1}`. However I found that I couldn't add brackets to the commands. How can I achieve this effect?

Also, I don't want to newcommand `\eqref{#1}` and `\Eqref{#1}` separately, because I the other `\ref` commands such as `\figref{#1}` and `\Figref{#1}` needn't the brackets and they all work properly.

[image: The effect of package refstyle]

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\newref{eq}{name={eq.~},Name={Eq.~}}

\title{This is a title}
\author{Mingyu Hsia}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \hat H\psi=E\psi
    \label{1}
\end{equation}

The above \eqref{1} is the eigenfunction. \Eqref{1} is also...

However, I want the effect is

The above eq. (\ref{1}) is the eigenfunction. Eq. (\ref{1}) is also...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is using the `cleveref` package and its user-level macros `\cref` and `\Cref` an option for you? For objects associated with the `equation` counter, these macros will automatically add parentheses around the equation number being cross-referenced.

Comment: Off-topic: In English writing (no idea about other languages!), it's customary *not* to abbreviate a word if it occurs at the start of a sentence. E.g., instead of `Eq. (\ref{1}) is...`, try `Equation (\ref{1}) is...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\newref{eq}{refcmd=(\ref{#1}),name=eq.~,Name=Eq.~}
```

[image]

For more information, see section 4.6 of the package documentation.